# Unable to access files inside docker centos container

Tags: linux, docker, centos, containers, amazon-linux

I was using centos image quite long time, when trying to build same docker image on different machine, it is throwing permission denied error.

```
ls: cannot access '.': Operation not permitted
```

Tried to change different base centos version. Still same error thrown. As part of debugging found it is throwing error while installing Python from source.

```
RUN yum install -y bzip2-devel libffi-devel && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz\
   && tar xzf Python-3.7.3.tgz && cd Python-3.7.3 && ./configure --enable-optimizations && make altinstall && rm ../Python-3.7.3.tgz
```

By removing above statement from Dockerfile and built image and insider the container I'm not able to access files..

```
$docker run -it centos8-test bash
#ls -la
ls: cannot access '.': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access '..': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'bin': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'boot': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'dev': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'etc': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'home': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'lib': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'lib64': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'media': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'mnt': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'opt': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'proc': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'root': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'run': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'sbin': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'srv': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'sys': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'tmp': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'usr': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'var': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access '.dockerenv': Operation not permitted
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .dockerenv
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bin
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? boot
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dev
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? etc
```

**Docker Version:**

```
docker --version
Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086
```

**Host OS details:**

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Comment: I was able to access files inside container in privileged mode, But I've to access files as part of building docker image.